# Is new facebook Limited Login acceptable on Android?

Tags: android, facebook-login

I see tutorial for IOS, but it doesn't have any tutorial for native android(only react native). That's why I decided to ask, may be somebody already investigated this question.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login

Comment: Have you ever figure out ?

Comment: no, I haven't. In our app it is not so important, we can just ignore this api.

Answer (score 3):

Facebook Limited Login is related to iOS only. It's because of the new terms of usage for iOS 14.5 and forcing using App Tracking Transparency framework. So, it's not related for Android and you should use the regular way on this platform.

As for iOS, developers are allowed to use a regular FB Login on iOS with version 14.4 or less. But since 14.5 developers must show ATT popup and choose a way of login dependently on the user answer.